# Integration with square root involved

Tags: integration

How to compute the integral of $\sqrt{1-r^2}$ with respect to $r$? Is there a substitution? What are the steps? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The standard substitution is

$$ r = \sin t \implies dr = \cos t dt$$

Hence

$$ \int \sqrt{1-r^2}  = \int \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 t } \cos t dt = \int \cos^2 t dt$$

and this is an easier integral since you can use the fact that

$$ \cos^2 t = \frac{1 - \cos 2t}{2} $$

Comment: Almost the same as mine...deleting it, upvoting this one. +1

Comment: Don!! Soy DonAnselmo... Como estas? a los siglos. :)

Comment: Ah, cambiaste de nombre...¿por qué? Yo bien, y espero que tú también. Un abrazo.